# PostgreSQL Job Scheduler on Azure DB for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, azure

In Azure Database for PostgreSQL, how do I install a pgAgent?
As, its a PaaS only, I will not have access to the Server. In that case, if I need a pgAgent to install, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

As per azure docs, it seems PgCron is available in flexible server type.